# How many permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ begin with an even number?

Tags: combinatorics

I came across the following problem, and I am looking for some help,

How many permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ begin with an even number?

My workings,

So in the set of numbers there are $2$ even numbers, $2$ and $4$, and we must fill $5$ positions with the beginning number being even,

We have $2$ options for the first position, $5$ options for the second position, $5$ options for the third position, $5$ options for the 4th position, and finally $5$ options for the last position, so therefore by the product rule

$$2\times5\times5\times5\times5 = 2 \times 5^4 = 2\times625 = 1250$$

Comment: In a permutation, the five numbers must be distinct.

Comment: so no repetition?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Please use \times to get $\times$

Comment: @Lordsharktheunknown so then would it be 2 options for the first position, 4 options for the next position, 3 options for the next position, 2 options for the next position and finally 1 option for the last position? therefore $2\times4\times3\times2\times1= 2\times4! = 2\times24 = 28?$

Comment: @user123 $2\times 4!=48$ looks right

Comment: similarly, 5! are the total number of permutations.  1/5 of which start with 2 and another 1/5 start with 4 or:  2/5 * 5! = 48

Comment: how could I use the formula $P(n,r) = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ where $n$ is the number of objects to choose from and $r$ is is pick the number of objects?

Comment: would it be correct to say that the first position can be filled by 2 then the other positions can be filled by $P(4,4) = 4!$ So therefore the number of permutations is $2*4!$?

Comment: @user123 Yes, that is correct

Comment: awesome thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be correct if the question said you can reuse numbers. However, in a *permutation*, you cannot repeat numbers.

With this in mind, we have $\color{blue}2$ options for the first position, $\color{blue}4$ options for the second position, $\color{blue}3$ options for the third position, $\color{blue}2$ options for the 4th position, and only $\color{blue}1$ option for the last position, so therefore by the product rule we have $$2\times4\times3\times2\times1 = 48$$ permutations.

More succinctly, we have $\color{blue}2$ options for the first position, and we wish to **permute** the rest of the $\color{blue}4$ numbers available to us. Hence we have

$$2 \times 4! = 48$$ even-leading permutations.

Answer (score 1):

For the first position you have two choices as you said.  But we do not consider repetition in permutations. Hence the other digits can be permuted in $4!$ ways.
Hence the answer would be $2*4!=48$